# Browser Control With No GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, browser, macros

I'm a Social Media Manager for Musicians and Bands across the globe, and have run in to a snag and am looking for anyones opinion who can help on the matter!

I'm using a service called Ping.FM that I use for updating status messages across multiple social networks. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the development team is in the works anymore and two of the networks no longer work, Tagged and MyYearBook. Now, these two services have no custom service API, email update, or really any kind of function for updating status messages other then using a mouse, keyboard, and browser.

Now the second part. I have a shared web host (HostGator)  that I use to run and leave Python scripts running to do my bidding whenever needed. What I'm thinking of is writing a script that will monitor an email account. When an email is received, it'll post the body as a status message.

Now the tricky part, how to post the status message. The shared host is all terminal only, no GUI. If there was a GUI, I would just use something like iMacro with Firefox and a Python script to alter it in order to post the status messages. Unfortunately though, no GUI, so as far as I'm aware it's not possible.

Is there any method of doing an idea like this, but without a GUI? Something terminal based, that can achieve the same idea? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If the services you're trying to use provide no API, you're pretty much out of luck. The only way I could think of to get around this would be to use something like cURL, you might be able to use it to simulate a login (submit login POST data via cURL to the same address that the login form sends the data to), then once logged in (you should be able to figure out whether the login worked by using a regex on the cURL response or something) use cURL to send POST data again, this time sending your status message to wherever they're normally submitted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* websites have an API, called HTTP. You can use [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to access it, so long as it doesn't use JavaScript for dynamic display.

Comment: This looks pretty interesting! It actually will be in handy for adding in a third social network I've been messing around with. Unfortunately, the two I had mention I do believe use javascript to generate their content. Is there any other methods of doing this that might react to javascript better?

Comment: Likely. Try searching this site.

Comment: Ended up making this work the way I wanted to using mobile versions of website and mobile useragents. Everything was pure HTML. :D Only having issues with Google+, but I have another topic for that. Thanks for the help!